Prevent vaulting of duplicate cards using PayPal SDK in PHP without access to card details
I am using the PayPal SDK to process payments and vault credit card information after an order is created. The flow is as follows:

An order is created.

PayPal SDK captures the order with the entered card details (we
don't have access to these card details on theclient side as the PayPal SDK renders the card fields)

On success,the card is vaulted against the customer's ID.


The issue I'm facing is that if a same user enters the same card again, the card is vaulted a second time, creating duplicate vaulted cards.
What I need:

If the user tries to vault the same card again, it should not be
vaulted.
We don't have access to the card details on the client side, so we
can't compare card numbers directly.

My current attributes for vaulting are:
  $payment_source = $customer_exist ? [
  "card" => [
    "attributes" => [
      "customer" => [
        "id" => $customer_id,
      ],
    ],
    "vault" => [
      "store_in_vault" => "ON_SUCCESS",
      "usage_type" => "PLATFORM",
      "customer_type" => "CONSUMER",
      "permit_multiple_payment_tokens" => true,
    ],
    "verification" => [
      "method" => "SCA_ALWAYS",  // or "SCA_WHEN_REQUIRED"
    ]
  ],
  "experience_context" => [
    "shipping_preference" => "NO_SHIPPING",
    "return_url" => isset($return_url) && $return_url ? $return_url : "https://example.com",
    "cancel_url" => "https://example.com"
  ]
] : null;

What I've tried:
I set "permit_multiple_payment_tokens" => false to prevent multiple tokens, but this didn't resolve the issue.

Since we don't have access to the actual card details (only the tokenized version managed by PayPal), is there a way to check if the card is already vaulted before creating a new entry for it?
Any suggestions on how to solve this?

"The issue I'm facing is that if a same user enters the same card again, the card is vaulted a second time" -- if the user is asked to enter the credit card details, your vaulting process seems not to be operating properly. Vaulting should avoid exactly this situation.
This details the JS flow, but the information ought to be the same for PHP: https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/paypal/vault/javascript/v3/

Actually We are giving Options whether user enter new card or use previously saved card so i want to handle the use case in any case if user enter same card and fill the checkbox to save card it should not vaulted again

Don't prevent it.
When cards are vaulted, store the last 4 digits of the card. Display currently vaulted cards when the user attempts to add another, so they can see it's already there.
The odds of the same user having two different cards that end with the same last 4 digits are very low, so in theory you could reject duplicates based on that. I would not bother though.

I am currently handling the scenario where a user may attempt to add the same card that is already vaulted during order creation. Although the chances are low that a user will enter the same card, PayPal doesn't seem to address this specific use case.
To prevent saving duplicate cards in the user database, I've added a check that compares the last four digits of the card before saving it as a vaulted card.
